# Place a block of HTML above the Megamenu in Joomla! 3.4.0 Purity_III template

Tags: joomla, menu, templating, joomla3.4

I need to place a block of HTML above the Megamenu. This block of HTML occupies the whole horizontal space above the Megamenu. I am using Joomla! 3.4.0 and the Purity_III template.

Anyone here can please tell how this can be done?

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried so far and any issues your coming across?

Comment: It's going to depend on whether the menu is positioned absolutely. You'll need to add some custom CSS or/and do a template override. That said, I'm voting to close. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to modify the file: 
public_html/site/templates/purity_iii/tpls/blocks/header.php

I added the following code after the code <div class='container'>:

        <div style='margin-bottom: 10px; font-family: arial; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 20px;'>
            THINGS I WANT TO WRITE
        </div>

Indeed, this writes above the megamenu, but then the megamenu starts appearing hover the text of the site.

Yes, I know I have to write CSS code. The question is I don't know what to write!

The file header.php is a custom file for the purity template. I didn't write it myself.